# What is this (moss/mold?) growing in my Dill flowerpot?

Tags: identification, moss

There are some little things that look like moss growing next to the Dill. They don't really look like tiny Dills, but I have no idea what it is.

The pot is on a 5th story window in a very urban part of NYC so it's unlikely to be some spore or something that flew in the window; also, all the other pots next to it don't have this moss growing in it. The soil all came from the same bag too.

[image]

[image]

Sorry, the pictures aren't great.

Comment: How long has the potting soil been in the pot?

Comment: Hmm, hard to guess. Maybe 6 or 7 months

Comment: Was it new potting soil, straight from the bag, and a clean pot with drainage holes?

Comment: It's second use, my first batch of dill seeds never grew, so I poured out the soil into a bag, soaked it a lot, and put new seeds in. When doing that I also cleaned the pot, but just with a rinse really.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answers in comments. It's just moss, possibly algae and maybe lichen. Algae and lichen will grow inside a brand new, unopened bag of potting soil left out in the light if the soil inside isn't bone dry, so its just in the soil anyway. The likeliest explanation is the fact the soil in the pot is too wet and has been for a while, and it's the second time you've used the soil (after saturating it), creating perfect conditions for this to grow. Just scrape it off the top, top up with fresh potting soil if necessary, keep the contents drier OR, if there are no drainage holes in the pot, find another pot that has some. Water when the surface of the soil in the pot is just about dry to the touch, and water thoroughly. If you stand the pot on an outer tray, empty that 30 minutes after watering so the pot is not left sitting in water.